# Jazz - Http 408 trying to authenticate

Tags: curl, rtc, ibm-jazz

I am trying to authenticate to Jazz (Rational Team Concert) using curl. I've read the documentation and many examples on how to do that.

When I try authenticating I get an HTTP 408 Request Timeout. Any ideas?

```
$ curl -i -k -d "j_username=myuser" -d "j_password=mypwd" "https://myserver:9443/jazz/authenticated/j_security_check"
HTTP/1.1 408 Request Timeout
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Language: en
Content-Length: 1367
Date: Fri, 03 Jun 2016 18:58:20 GMT
Connection: close
```

Comment: On my test setup, with default installation of 6.0.3, the url for authentication is /jazz/authenticated/j_security_check i.e. not /jazz/... - edited like this, and for my server hostname and username/password, your curl command works for me.